# A parabola with focus $(3,4)$ touches $y=x$ and $y=0$. Find its directrix, equation of parabola and vertex.

Tags: contest-math, conic-sections

The following problem is taken from the practice set of JEE exam.

> A parabola with focus $(3,4)$ touches $y=x$ and $y=0$. Find its directrix, equation of parabola and vertex.

I could not picture this parabola. I thought the statement was wrong. But in the hint they have written this:

> Directrix is the line joining the image of $(3,4)$ in $y=x$ and $y=0$.

Image of $(3,4)$ in $y=x$ is $(4,3)$ and in $y=0$ is $(3,-4)$. Equation of line through these two points is $7x-y-25=0$

My doubt is: why is directrix obtained by joining the image of focus about two tangents?

Do we need to use here the property that the tangents at the extremities of a focal chord of a parabola intersect at right angle on the directrix? But not sure how to use this here.

Comment: *"why is directrix obtained by joining the image of focus about two tangents?"* The reflection of the focus $F$ in the tangent at $P$ is specifically the projection (say, $P'$) of $P$ onto the directrix. This is effectively the reflection property of the parabola, which says that the tangent at $P$ bisects $\angle FPP'$ (along with the *definitional* property that $|FP|=|PP'|$).

Comment: The axis, being perpendicular to the directrix, is $x+7y+k=0$ and passes through the focus, making $k=-31.$ The axis intersects the parabola $(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2=(7x-y-25)^2/(7^2+1^2)$ in the vertex $(\frac{89}{25},\frac{98}{25}).$

Comment: @Blue Thank you.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F = (3, 4)$ and let $P$ be the point of tangency between the parabola and a tangent line.  The reflection of $F$ about the tangent line produces $F'$ that is has
the property that $|FP|= |F'P|$ and also we have that $PF'$ is orthogonal to the directrix (because it is parallel to the axis of the parabola), therefore $F'$ lies on the directrix.  Two such lines determine two images of the focus that both lie on the same line.  Therefore the direction is just the line connecting the two focus images.

The reflection image of $(3, 4)$ across $y = x$ is $(4, 3)$ and across $y = 0$ is $(3, -4)$, therefore the equation of the directrix is

$  y = 3 + 7 (x - 4) = 7 x - 25 $

The equation of the parabola is

$ (x - 3)^2 + (y - 4)^2 = ( 7 x - y - 25 )^2 / (7^2 + 1^2) $

Distance of $(3, 4)$ from the directrix is $(21 - 4 - 25)/\sqrt{50} = \dfrac{8}{5\sqrt{2} } $

The axis is along the vector $(7, -1)$, so the vertex is given by

$ (3, 4) + \dfrac{4}{50} (7, -1) =  (3 + \dfrac{14}{25}, 4 - \dfrac{2}{25} ) = (\dfrac{89}{25}, \dfrac{98}{25} )$

Comment: Can you explain how you calculated the vertex? Thanks.

Comment: Reflecting $F$ about the tangent line that passes through $P$ to obtain $ F ' $ implies that $|FP|  = |F'P|$ by the principle of reflection, or as you mentioned by congruent triangles.  For the second point, concerning why $F'P$ is parallel to the axis.  This follows from the reflection property of the parabola, namely, that a ray originating at the focus, and reflected at a point on the parabola, is reflected such that the reflected ray is parallel to the axis of the parabola.

Comment: Yes, I understood that after reading Blue's comment above. So, I deleted my comment. Sorry for that. Thankyou for the answer and quick replies.

Comment: We can find vertex by the intersection of the curve and the axis. But your method seems more ingenious. Can you explain? Thanks.

Comment: The focus and the vertex lie on the axis whose direction is known (using the equation of the directrix, and using also a sketch of the parabola with respect to the xy, also the distance between the focus and the vertex is half the distance between the vertex and the directrix.

Comment: I understand the directrix is $7x-y-25=0$. From this, how do we conclude the direction of axis is $(7,-1)$?

Comment: The direction vector of the axis is the normal vector (perpendicular) to the directrix.  The normal to the line $ax + by + c = 0$ is the vector $(a,b)$.  However the direction can also be $(-a, -b)$.  So in this problem, the direction from the focus to the vertex can be along the vector $(7, -1)$ or $(-7, 1)$.  To determine which one, you need a simple sketch of how the parabola opens up, and use common sense, and then take you direction from the focus to the vertex as the opposite of that direction.